# App to turn off airplane mode on android

Tags: android, airplane-mode

First little background why i need to write this app. 
My phone got wet and unfortunately screen doesn't work now
(I can't see anything and I can't press anything).
Phone has airplane mode turn on so my photos cannot synchronize.
I cannot connect with USB cable because it is in "Only recharge state".
USB debugging is turn off so I cannot connect with adb to turn off airplane mode.
But there is a little light in a tunnel. There is WIFI working. 
I hear a sound when it connects to my network so I know it's working.
My idea is to write a simple app that will turn off airplane mode.
I'll install it from PC using Play Store but I need a way to turn it on. 
I think it can be done by registering this app as a listener to some system call. Can Play Store register app as a listener without a need to run this app?

Do you think that's all possible? 
Maybe someone has other idea?

Thanks!

Comment: if it is connected to the wifi, how comes your photos are not synchronizing?

Comment: If WiFi works, why it is not syncing? And it's not possible. Any `BroadcastReceiver` only get activated after the user opens the app for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

From android 4.2: This is no longer possible, except by apps that are signed by the firmware signing key or are installed on the system partition (typically by a rooted device user). (Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2))

Android 4.1 and below:

```
// read the airplane mode setting
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
      getContentResolver(), 
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;

// toggle airplane mode
Settings.System.putInt(
      getContentResolver(),
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

// Post an intent to reload
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Also add the WRITE_SETTINGS permission to your android manifest

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android)

You may be able to open the settings with this code and tell the user to disable airplane mode:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17){
    try{
        Intent intentAirplaneMode = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS);
        intentAirplaneMode.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intentAirplaneMode);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("exception", e + "");
    }
}
else{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS");
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Coped from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782171/how-should-i-programmatically-open-the-flight-mode-setting-page-on-samsung-devic)

Comment: I was afraid of that... Unfortunately my phone has 4.4 android and it's unrooted... :/ Thank you for help

Comment: I had made an edit for you with how to open up the settings to get the user to change airplane mode. If it helped give it an up vote - if it answers your question (better than other answers) then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am not aware how to programmatically build an app to turn on/off system settings, but what I can tell you is, there is an app already available in Play Store which I feel does the same thing.

You can have a look at this app, called **Trigger**.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher&hl=en

All you have to do is to create a task to turn the Airplane mode Off and that task can be triggered through Wi-Fi.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately screen doesn't work so I cannot see any thing, also I cannot tap the screen. Creating anything is not an option. But thank you for idea.

Comment: Okay! You can check if there are any other possibilities with that app or not. Otherwise I will not be able to help you. All the best :)